# How can I set up state in a React app using arrays in a json object as well as arrays not in the json object?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, state

I have a json object which I have set the state of my app to

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = DATA;
 }
```

The json object has a an array of product objects.
I would also like to add an empty array to the state.
This array with have products pushed into it when the user clicks on the product. 
This array doesn't exist in the json object.
How can I set this up as this.state = DATA;

Comment: You should provide some more info here. For example shape of your object and most probably what have you tried with your code? You can shape your state anyway you like, why don't you add relative sections for your needs? `state = { data: DATA, products: []}`

Comment: are you fetching data or you importing json from local folder?

Answer (score 3):

React state accepts the objects. So if you wanna initialize your state with an empty array, you can assign like this

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
data : blahblahblah,
products : []
      }
   }
}
```

And For example, when you wanna access the product array , you can update using

```js
 this.setState({products : [id:'1', product_name : 'something']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intialise the state in your constructor as,

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
       data:DATA,
       products:[]
   }
 }
```

And when your select a product you will have to push new items into product array like,

```
addProduct(item){
  let products=[...this.state.products];
  prosucts.push(item);
  tis.setState({products:products});
}
```